# Using R to find a T/F answer for one observation based on other observations sharing the same level of a different variable

Tags: r

So I have a very large (confidential, hence the vague names) data set containing a number of variables, and let's call the relevant ones `group` and `dummy1`. What I want to do is create a new variable, `dummy2`, that determines whether `dummy1` is true (or 1 in this case) for at least one observation with the same value for `group`. This variable must have a value for every observation, even when `dummy1` is `NA` for someone in the `group` (there are no `NA`s in `group`).  I am very new to R and programming generally so I have not been able to figure out how to extract this information from `aggregate` for use in a variable, which seems like what you'd want to do, but I'm stuck.

So here is a chunk of what my data would hypothetically end up looking like:

```
Obs. Group Dummy1 Dummy2
1    101   0      1
2    101   1      1 
3    101   0      1 
4    102   0      0 
5    102   0      0 
6    103   1      1 
7    103   1      1 
8    103   1      1
```

So the idea here is that since at least one person in Group 101 has a value of 1 for `dummy1`, all members of that group get a 1 in `dummy2`, and likewise since nobody in Group 103 has `dummy1`, all members of group 103 have a 0 value for `dummy2`.  The dataset has close to 7k observations over 1300 groups, so I need some kind of loop setup I suspect, but can anybody help me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I think here `plyr` and `ddply` will be a better bet

```
require(plyr)
ddply(data, .(Group), transform, Dummy2 = 1 * any(Dummy1, na.rm = TRUE))

##    Obs. Group Dummy1 dummy2
## 1    1   101      0      1
## 2    2   101      1      1
## 3    3   101      0      1
## 4    4   102      0      0
## 5    5   102      0      0
## 6    6   103      1      1
## 7    7   103      1      1
## 8    8   103      1      1
```

If for any reason you want more speed to process to your data, then `data.table` can be used

```
require(data.table)
data <- as.data.table(data)
data[, Dummy2:= 1 * any(Dummy1, na.rm = TRUE), by = "Group"]

data
##    Obs. Group Dummy1 Dummy2
## 1:    1   101      0      1
## 2:    2   101      1      1
## 3:    3   101      0      1
## 4:    4   102      0      0
## 5:    5   102      0      0
## 6:    6   103      1      1
## 7:    7   103      1      1
## 8:    8   103      1      1
```

EDIT : Added `na.rm = TRUE` is `any` to deal with missing value thanks to @Dwin

Comment: +1 but I really hate how this comes off as if `data.table` should be a second choice, when it's obviously the first (because it's both faster and shorter and easier to read/understand); also the quotes around Group are unnecessary

Comment: @eddi You are right in this case the `data.table` solution look simpler than the `plyr` one, but I usually assume (may be I'm wrong) than new R users are more familiar with `plyr` than `data.table`. That being said, I see more and more `data.table` questions here and I like to think that few years ago it was `plyr` against `aggregate` or `tapply`. useR will always go for the most easiest/efficient solutions and `data.table` despite the small learning curve is gaining a lot attention

Comment: @DWin Adding  `na.rm = TRUE` to `any` will solve the first problem some NA mixed with values. But If for one group there are only `NA`, the OP didn't say what he wants to do (0 or NA) ?

Comment: No group has only NA values, although in general the nature of the data point is such that an NA essentially is a 0.  Meanwhile I've been trying to run these methods on my data and getting `Dummy2` all equal to 1, rather than a mix as it should be... Is there some trick to this beyond just plugging my variable and dataframe names into the code above?

Comment: I've tried different data types for `dummy1` (logical, numeric, integer) with no effect, as well as changing NAs to 0s prior to running the data.table methods.

Comment: @BenEichler with the sample data you provide it works..so may be there's something different in your data we don't know. If you can find out what and update the example I could help you. Basically, I need more info (`str(data)` and if is not too big or not confidential you can `dput(data)`).

Answer (score 2):

```
df$Dummy2 <- with(df, ave(Dummy1 , Group, 
                                FUN=function(x) max(c(0,x), na.rm=TRUE) ) )
```

Test object:

```
df <- structure(list(Obs. = 1:8, Group = c(101L, 101L, 101L, 102L, 
102L, 103L, 103L, 103L), Dummy1 = c(0L, NA, 0L, NA, NA, 1L, NA, 
1L), Dummy2 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1)), .Names = c("Obs.", 
"Group", "Dummy1", "Dummy2"), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: I tried your solution and when we have only NA for one group it doesn't solve the problem either. But thanks for pointing that  my first solution was not correct when I have some NA mixed with values for one group

Comment: When I run it with all NA's within a group of Dummy1's I get 0's for Dummy2. (That was the whole point of testing `c(0, x)` .)

Comment: My bad, I had a mistake in my testing data, I tried and now it works but using `any(..., na.rm = TRUE)` seems to work too

Comment: +1 Thanks for adding your testing data and for pointing this shortcoming (how to deal with NA).